# Рефакторинг кода. Как оптимизировать количество if?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть код, который принимает json данные и в зависимости от типа выполнить определённые действия.
Весь код обработки находится в if'ах, добавление новых типов оказалось неудобным.
Сейчас планирую вынести обработку в отдельные сервисы под каждый тип, а информацию передавать с помощью DTO. Но, это все равно не избавляет от сложности и количество if. Рассматривал возможность заменить на switch/match, но, такой вариант кажется не совсем верным. С похожей проблемой столкнулся и в другой части кода, где нужно обрабатывать по-разному в зависимости от состояния.

```
if ('text' === $message->getType()) {
    // code
}
if ('poll' === $message->getType()) {
    // code
}
if ('image' === $message->getType()) {
    // code
}
```

С ООП немного знаком в теории, на практике, осмысленно, применять получается редко.
Насколько я знаю в решении проблемы должен помочь полиморфизм, но, как правильно его применить не пойму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это похоже на Стратегию. Но как я полагаю в вашем случае там всё равно придётся для него `if`'ы

Но для облегчения решения проблемы я бы предложил сделать мапу. Наглядно:

- Выделяем интерфейс для классов с логикой:

  ```
  interface StrategyInterface {
      public function execute(array $data): void;
  }
  ```

  тут входные и выходные данные те, что вам нужны. Например входных параметров может не быть. Или может что-то возвращать. Это понятно.
- Делаем разные классы, которые имплементируют интерфейс

  ```
    class TextHandler implemets StrategyInterface {

        public function execute(array $data): void {
            DB::user->save($data);        
        }
    }

    class PollHandler implemets StrategyInterface {

        public function execute(array $data): void {
            $implodedData = implode(', ', $data);
            $stringWithoutUnderscore = str_replace('_', '', $implodedData);
            file_put_contents('file.txt', $stringWithoutUnderscore );
        }
    }

    class ImageHandler implemets StrategyInterface {

        public function execute(array $data): void {
            header("Content-Type: image/png");
            $im = imagecreate($data['width'], $data['height']);
                or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");
            $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
            $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $data['r'], $data['g'], $data['b']);
            imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
            imagepng($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }
    }
  ```
- Далее делается какой-то менеджер с хранилищем ссылок:

  ```
    class HandlersManager {

        const HANDLER_TEXT = 'text';
        const HANDLER_POLL = 'poll';
        const HANDLER_IMAGE = 'image';

        public static function handlersMap(): array {
            return [
                HANDLER_TEXT => TextHandler::class,
                HANDLER_POLL => PollHandler::class,
                HANDLER_IMAGE => ImageHandler::class,       
            ];
        }
    }
  ```

  Константы скорее всего можно определить в каждом классе в виде свойства и брать вместо `HANDLER_TEXT` что-то типа `TextHandler::getName()` который будет возвращать значение, в свойстве `$name`. Базовый метод `getName` можно написать в каком-то базовом классе для всех тех хэндлеров.
- Далее мы например получаем `$_GET` запрос с каким-то параметром. Например в `$_GET['handler_type']` будет необходимое значение. Получается:

  ```
    $handlersMap = HandlersManager::handlersMap();
    $handler = new $handlersMap($_GET['handler_type']);
    $handler->execute($_GET['handler_data']);
  ```

---

P.S. Можно создать базовый класс и передавать `data` в конструктор, а у обработчика просто вызывать `->execute()`;